# JQuery JEditable - How to Disable on click editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

I was wondering if you can stop text being editable on click?  I have a separate edit button to make the text editable and that's the only way that I want the user to be able to edit the text, so want to turn off the on click editing?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Britt is right, add a custom event, and trigger it with a button for example. Here is some code to explain it:

The custom event:

```
$('#id').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', {
    event : 'custom_event'
});
```

And the trigger:

```
<button onclick="$('#id').trigger('custom_event');">click to trigger</button>
```

Comment: That will prevent you to allow mouseover if you use event for custom-event ?

Comment: @Lutsen, really great solution. It took some time to understand your solution but after it, it's working like charm. I was seeking this answer since so many days (around 8 to 10 days). But then I prayed to Stackover Angel and finally I found this solution. I also thumbs up your solution.

Answer (score 2):

There's an undocumented option **event** that you can use when you create your jEditable fields.

*(It's not actually undocumented but it's just mentioned off-hand in one sentence on the jEditable docs page.)*

You can use it to change the event that makes the field editable.  You can use any jquery event, even custom events.

For example, on my project I created an edit.mode event that makes the field editable which I can then trigger however I like, with a button, a hotkey, whatever.

Comment: A am appreciating your answer too for great explanation which I couldn't understood while reviewing doc for jEditable.

Comment: I am a little confused as to what the 'event' value represents.  Is it a function name?

Comment: Ignore the above question... it was stupid and I understand what it is now.  Sorry... I asked before I thought... happens sometimes.  There was something missing which was the unbinding part that I was interested in but found it later (sort of like a toggle).